# FXO Port on Raspberry Pi Model 3B

Tags: hardware

Is their any chance to  do customization of this platform Raspberry Pi Model 3B 
to Have FXO Port to be work with Asterisks PBX Software ??

Comment: Are you looking for an add on, or to have a modified version of the board produced.

Comment: Dear . Steve  , Thank you a lot for Fast & clear answer , yes i will work on the  modified version of the board produced .

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an add on fort a small number of boards, this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-a-pstn) has a few options.

If instead you are looking to produce a custom board for a commercial product Element 14 offers a [Pi customization service](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-76955/l/raspberry-pi-customization-service) (5,000 piece minimium)  or to have a modified version of the board produced. If the latter this is the place to start element14.com/community/docs/DOC-76955/l/…

Comment: No that is a big gulf between consumer or maker level production  and OEM  production run numbers. I think your only option is going to be one of the solutions from the linked answer. with a 1000 units you may be able to get a reasonable discount from the manufacturer or one of their resellers. Obviously this cost would need to be built into the cost of your product. If you are willing to give up the Pi you may be able to arrange some small unit production (1k units) in China, but this is outside my experience.

Comment: i will try to contact the manufacturer or one of their resellers as you advice me . Thanks Steve